# jquery play/pause replace text and revert text

Tags: jquery, youtube, chromeless

**what I have tried so far here** : http://jsfiddle.net/yusaf/VVEY9/26/

I have a problem with my pause and play replacing and reverting

1. How can I have the `.pause` hidden on page load
2. when `.play` is clicked replace the element with the `.pause` element
3. when `.pause` is clicked revert to `.play` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var obj = $('object')
     .wrap('<div id="test"></div>')
     .find('embed').attr('src', function(i,s){return s+'&enablejsapi=1&version=3'}).end()
     .find('param[name=movie]').attr('value', function(i,v){return v+'&enablejsapi=1&version=3'}).end()
     .detach()
     .appendTo($('#test'));

 $('.play').click(function(){
  obj.find('embed')[0].playVideo();
 });
 $('.pause').click(function(){
  obj.find('embed')[0].pauseVideo();
 })

 $('.pause').hide();
});

$(".play").click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.pause').show();
});

$(".pause").click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.play').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the correction here :

http://jsfiddle.net/VVEY9/52/

You can remove the two last "click" functions.